# How to find what apache.xerces version does spring-framework use?

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring-framework v5.2.1.RELEASE. The DefaultDocumentLoader.java in spring bean factory has following code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
...
DocumentBuilder builder = createDocumentBuilder(factory, entityResolver, errorHandler);
```

I know that spring uses `apache.xerces.internal.parsers`. But I don't know which version of Xerces does it use? In spring directory, I did `gradlew -q dependencies` and searched the dependency list.
I did not find xerces or parsers. How to figure out the xerces version in use?

Comment: Have you checked the resulting jar or the manifest ?

Comment: Spring uses the default XML stuff of the JDK it doesn't use a dependency for that.

Comment: I am using openjdk 1.8. Is xerces included by the JDK installation? Where I can find the default XML?

Comment: Are you using eclipse ?

Comment: no I am not using eclipse. I simply use gradle to build my java application, which uses spring. And the spring use xerces. I loss the track there. I find out that I don't know where does the spring pick up xercers nor the version of it.

Comment: My build result is an tomcat WAR file. I searched the whole directory tree and found no jar file has xercers in its name.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243062/how-do-i-figure-out-what-version-of-xerces-used-in-my-openjdk-library/74081475#74081475

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It uses the JDK's default library for XML parser. So, it is not using any third party jar for parsing XML.*

Basically, it is using the **rt.jar** of your **jdk/../jre/lib** directory for getting classes to parse XML.

The package it is using is : `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*`

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful! I have no idea xerces is included inside rt.jar. No online tutorial tells me that. Thanks a lot!