# how do I figure out what version of xerces used in my OpenJDK library?

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a Java application using Spring framework. Spring uses the Apache Xerces library which is included inside rt.jar comes with my java OpenJDK 8 installation. I wonder how do I know what exact version of Xerces is used in rt.jar?

The suggested answer at [How to find what apache.xerces version does spring-framework use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224137/how-to-find-what-apache-xerces-version-does-spring-framework-use) does not answer my question here. It does not tell how to find out the xerces version from rt.lib

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find what apache.xerces version does spring-framework use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224137/how-to-find-what-apache-xerces-version-does-spring-framework-use)

Comment: @marc That doesn't answer the question which version of Xerces is included in OpenJDK 8.

Answer (score 2):

Up to java 8 you check the bundled xerces version with:

```
java com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.Version
```

After java 8 (i.e from java 9 upwards) you can extract the `jmods/java.xml.jmod` with:

```
jmod extract java.xml.jmod
```

And then look in the just extracted `legal/xerces.md`. Usually the version is on the first line stated as a commented text.